# Some "sources" in Cydia are empty - how to get the content?

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia

I've just upgraded my iPhone 4 to iOS 5.0.1 and also jailbroken it. I've waited with the upgrade until the jailbreak because there are some tweaks I don't want to miss. Now that I have iOS5 jailbroken, I want to re-add those tweaks, but I don't find them in Cydia.

Looking at the sources in Cydia, I see that `Modmyi.com` and `Cydia/Telesphoreo` are listed and they *do* contain lots of items, but `Big Boss` and `Dev Team` and `cydia.zodttd.com` are also listed, but when I select each then there's nothing in there.

So it would appear that some of the repo's are not properly set up. To test this, I removed `Big Boss` and hit the "Add" button to add it again, but got an error message "Did not find repository".

Comment: What are your display filters? Cydia has the ability to hide developer and system packages. If you have developer and system packages turned off, and that is all that is in those repositories, they may look empty.

Comment: I had no filters set. As I mention in my answer below, the fault was that it remembered old sources whose repo's have moved.

Comment: They're set up by default. The first time you run cydia, it asks you to choose their settings.

Comment: I'm aware you have solved this problem for yourself. However, I think it may be useful to have information about the filters here for future reference, in case anyone else needs it in the future.

Comment: @FakeName: That's a good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, it turns out that the sources have moved. They're no longer located as specified in Cydia, so of course Cydia can't find any content.

The solution was to remove the faulty sources and add them again by following these instructions: http://www.appleiphoneschool.com/how-to-add-a-source-to-cydia/

Answer (score -2):

Restore your device using itune, then jailbreak again, its the best way to solve the problem.

Thanks.